# React firebase window.print() on safari wont run

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase, safari

I am using firebase and create react app for an app that creates a page that a user can print. This is all the code needed to replicate the problem. Everything works fine on Chrome. I updated all npm dependencies and firebase tools but it didnt fix the issue.

I think the problem is with firebase because I get data with a basic fetch api call and it works fine.

The firebaseIndex.js file is:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "FIREBASE_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "fakedomain",
  databaseURL: "https://appName.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "appName",
  storageBucket: "appName.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...,
  measurementId: ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

The index.js file is:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import firebase from './firebaseIndex.js'
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("user123").get().then(doc => {
      console.log("anything")
    })
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={e => window.print()}>Print</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  , document.getElementById('root'))
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

the html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="this is a web app"
    />
    <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" /> -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
<!--     <script src="/__/firebase/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="/__/firebase/7.5.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**Any help is greatly appreciated**. window.print() used to work on this app for safari but I just noticed it doesnt work anymore. I am on IOS 13.3.1 on an iphone 6. Maybe it is a bug with the new ios update? Even if someone can point me in the direction to report a bug to safari or firebase or react that would be great

Comment: it should work according to the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

Answer (score 0):

Start deleting unnecessary code and see if you can find a typo / syntax error.